# How to create a new rails app with a slim template as default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, slim-lang

I was recently introduced to Ruby on Rails and the slim template. As I create a new app using the `rails new appname` command, under app/views/layouts, there are the erb files such as:`application.html.erb`. As expected right? Is there any way for me to create a new rails application where instead of an `application.html.erb` file, it's `application.html.slim` from the get go?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the [`slim-rails`](https://github.com/slim-template/slim-rails) gem to your Gemfile and then all generated view files will use `.slim` extension.

It hasn't been updated in 2 years but it still works fine for me on Rails 6.

Comment: Do you mean I should create a Gemfile with `slim-rails` included before initializing `rails new appname`?

Comment: No, just after. The only file created upon rails new is application.html.erb, which you would have to leave as is or port to slim https://erb2slim.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can call the following template in the existing app it should setup slim for your app.

```
rails app:template LOCATION='https://railsbytes.com/script/X8Bska'
```

There are plenty of other helpful templates which you can use to speed up the setup

```
 https://railsbytes.com/
```